# Feed import many fields into single content type

Tags: 7, feeds

I have a content type that I want to import some sitenames and siteurls from a csv file. So basically create a node type with option to import csv file to fill up field types sitenames and siteurls under one project with feeds or any other solution need help

Setup: Drupal 7, Views 2, Feeds

Comment: There is a Views 2 branch for D7?

Answer (score 1):

You are in the correct path, the [Feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) will allow you to import into the a content type data from a CSV file. You should install the feeds module first, create the content type after and last map the columns of data on your CSV file to the content type fields.

If you want to manipulate the data first before creating the node the [Feeds Tamper module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) will help you do that.

**Note:** On the feed module page that are a couple of links to help you with the setup. Also Mustard Seed Media released a new podcast about the feed module as well.

Comment: So basically the feed tamper will loop through my file then add the content to the  fields which are unlimited